# Wireless disconnects on cable plug

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet

I work on Dell Precision M4800 and I would like to know If It's possible to be connected to the wired network(company) and wireless(unlocked) at the same time.
For now when I am connected to wireless network and it disconnects at the moment I plug a ethernet cable.
Is it possible to have both?
These are my network adapters:
Wired
Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-LM

Wireless
Dell Wireless 1550 802.11ac

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This question is off topic in network engineering. I would try asking in super user.

Comment: Yes. There's a setting in one of the controls (nic, wireless, dell apps) that tells it to use only one connection at a time. I'm not using a dell (windows) laptop, so I cannot point you to the exact spot.